# For $a,b,c>0$ such that $abc=1$, prove that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{6}{a+b+c}\ge5$

Tags: inequality

For $a,b,c>0$ such that $abc=1$, prove that $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{6}{a+b+c}\ge5$$
The sample solution is:

Assuming $a\ge b\ge c$, prove $$f(a,b,c)\ge f(a,\sqrt{bc},\sqrt{bc})\ge5$$

I can prove $f(a,\sqrt{bc},\sqrt{bc})\ge5$ it is equivalent to $(x-1)^2(2x^4+4x^3-4x^2-x+2)\ge0$ with $x=\sqrt{bc}$

Please help me prove $f(a,b,c)\ge f(a,\sqrt{bc},\sqrt{bc})$

Comment: $uvw$ kills it immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c})^2\geq 0 \Rightarrow b+c\geq 2\sqrt{bc}$$
$$a\geq b\geq c >0 \Rightarrow a+2\sqrt{bc}\geq 3\sqrt{bc},\ a+b+c\geq 3\sqrt{bc}$$
$$\frac{6}{a+b+c}-\frac{6}{a+2\sqrt{bc}}=-\frac{6(\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c})^2}{(a+2\sqrt{bc})(a+b+c)}\geq- \frac{6(\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c})^2}{(3\sqrt{bc})(3\sqrt{bc})}= -\frac{2}{3} \frac{(\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c})^2}{bc}$$
$$\frac1{b}+\frac1{c}-\frac2{\sqrt{bc}}=\frac{(\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c})^2}{bc}$$
$$f(a,b,c)-f(a,\sqrt{bc},\sqrt{bc})\geq \frac{(\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c})^2}{bc}-\frac{2}{3} \frac{(\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c})^2}{bc}= \frac{(\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c})^2}{3bc}\geq 0$$