# Possible approaches to prove $\frac {1}{a}+\frac {1}{b}+\frac {1}{c}+\frac {6}{a+b+c}\geq 5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am looking for various approaches to prove that the following inequality is true.

> Let $a,b,c>0$ with $abc =1$, prove that $$\frac {1}{a}+\frac {1}{b}+\frac {1}{c}+\frac {6}{a+b+c}\geq 5$$

My first approach.

C-S inequality didn't work .

$$\bigg(\frac {1}{a}+\frac {1}{b}+\frac {1}{c}\bigg)(a+b+c )\geq 9$$
$$\frac {9}{a+b+c}+\frac {6}{a+b+c}\geq 5$$
$$a+b+c≤3$$

But, by Am-Gm $a+b+c\geq 3\sqrt [3]{abc}=3$.

Next approach.

Am-Gm inequality didn't work .

$$\frac {1}{a}+\frac {1}{b}+\frac {1}{c}\geq 3\sqrt[3]{\frac {1}{abc}}=3$$

But, $$3+\frac {6}{a+b+c}\geq 5$$ is not necessarily true.

*Please share us, possible different and alternative approaches.*

Comment: if you know the pqr or similarly the uvw method, this is a nice exercise on those. My gut feeling is there is no very simple AM-GM would solve this.

Comment: What are these? @dezdichado

Comment: See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4690748/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use the $pqr$ method. In fact, this method is the same as the solution of @River Li above in the comment. New to this inequality world, I just use the most basic form of the $pqr$ method. So $p = a+b+c, q = ab+bc+ca, r = abc$. Note that $r = 1$ and is fixed. Thus in terms of $p,q,r$ we prove: $\dfrac{q}{r}+\dfrac{6}{p} \ge 5 \iff pq + 6r-5pr \ge 0$. Thus if we fix $q$ or $p$ then we get a linear function of the remaining unfixed variable, say $q$ for $p$ fixed. Hence $f(q) = pq+6r-5pr$ is a linear function in $q$. Thus the $q$-lemma says the minimum value of $f$ attains when $2$ of the $3$ variables $a,b,c$ in this case are equal. So WLOG, let's put $a = b = x$, then $c = \dfrac{1}{x^2}$. Thus the inequality becomes: $\dfrac{2}{x}+x^2+\dfrac{6x^2}{2x^3+1} \ge 5 \iff 2x^6 - 10x^4 + 11x^3 - 5x + 2 \ge 0 \iff (x-1)^2(2x^4+4x^3-4x^2-x+2) \ge 0$. But the second factor is a problem I posted earlier and posted my answer as well showing it $\ge 0$. Thus the inequality is proved by the $pqr$ method.

Comment: Nice. (+1) I usually call the method in your answer uvw method. The pqr method use only substitutions in terms of $p, q, r$ (of the well-known inequalities). For example, Schur's inequality $\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} a(a-b)(a-c) \ge 0$ is written as $p^3 - 4pq + 9r\ge 0$. In contrast, uvw method uses the so-called uvw theorem (or your q-lemma etc.) to conclude that we only need to check $a=b$ e.g..

Answer (score 4):

Non-specific technology .

---

Let $\thinspace a+b=m,\thinspace ab=n$, then we obtain :

$$
\begin{align}&\frac {a+b}{ab}+ab+\frac {6}{a+b+\frac {1}{ab}}≥5\\
\iff &\frac mn+n+\frac {6n}{mn+1}≥5\end{align}
$$

Without loss of generality, we assume that :

$$
\begin{align}&(a-1)(b-1)≥0\\
\iff &2\sqrt n ≤m≤n+1\end{align}
$$

Substituting $\thinspace n=x^2\wedge x>0$, then it sufficies to prove that :

$$
\begin{align}\frac {2}{x}+x^2+\frac {6x^2}{x^4+x^2+1}-5≥0
\end{align}
$$

which is equivalent to :

$$
\begin{align}x^5(x-1)^2&+(x-1)^4(2x^2+3x+2)≥0\end{align}
$$

and which holds $\forall x\in\mathbb R_{>0}\thinspace .$

Comment: Nice. (+1) We can rewrite your proof as follows. WLOG, assume that $(a-1)(b-1)\ge 0$ which results in $a + b \le ab + 1$.
By AM-GM, we have
$$LHS - RHS \ge 2\sqrt{\frac{1}{ab}} + \frac{1}{c} + \frac{6}{ab + 1 + c} - 5.$$
Let $x = \sqrt{ab}$. Then $c = 1/x^2$.
It suffices to prove that
$$2/x + x^2 + \frac{6}{x^2 + x + 1/x^2} - 5 \ge 0$$
which is equivalent to $x^5(x-1)^2+(x-1)^4(2x^2+3x+2) \ge 0$.

Answer (score 3):

*Here is two more proofs*.

**Proof 1**:

WLOG, assume that $c \ge 1$.

Let $f(a, b, c) := \frac {1}{a}+\frac {1}{b}+\frac {1}{c}+\frac {6}{a+b+c}-5$. We have
\begin{align*}
 f(a, b, c) - f(\sqrt{ab}, \sqrt{ab} , c) &= \frac1a + \frac1b - \frac{2}{\sqrt{ab}}
 + \frac{6}{a + b + c} - \frac{6}{2\sqrt{ab} + c}\\[6pt]
 &= \frac{a + b - 2\sqrt{ab}}{ab}
 - \frac{6(a + b - 2\sqrt{ab})}{(a + b + c)(2\sqrt{ab} + c)}\\[6pt]
 &\ge \frac{a + b - 2\sqrt{ab}}{ab}
 - \frac{6(a + b - 2\sqrt{ab})}{(2\sqrt{ab} + c)(2\sqrt{ab} + c)}\\[6pt]
 &= (a + b - 2\sqrt{ab})\left(c - \frac{6}{(2/\sqrt c + c)^2}\right)\\[6pt] 
 &\ge 0
\end{align*}
where we use $c - \frac{6}{(2/\sqrt c + c)^2} \ge 0$ for all $c \ge 1$.

It suffices to prove that
$$f(\sqrt{ab}, \sqrt{ab}, c) \ge 0$$
or
$$2\sqrt c + \frac{1}{c} + \frac{6}{2/\sqrt c + c} -5 \ge 0$$
which is equivalent to (letting $c = y^2$)
$$\left( 2\,{y}^{4}-{y}^{3}-4\,{y}^{2}+4\,y+2 \right)  \left( y
-1 \right) ^{2} \ge 0$$
which is true.

We are done.

---

**Proof 2**:

Let $x = \frac{1}{a}, y = \frac{1}{b}, z = \frac{1}{c}$.
Then $xyz = 1$.
We need to prove that
$$x + y + z + \frac{6}{1/x + 1/y + 1/z} \ge 5. \tag{1}$$

We use the pqr method.

Let $p = x + y + z, q = xy + yz + zx, r = xyz = 1$. (1) is written as
$$p + \frac{6}{q} \ge 5.\tag{2}$$

Using Schur's inequality
$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} x(x-y)(x-z) \ge 0$ which is written as $p^3 - 4pq + 9r \ge 0$, we have
$$q \le \frac{p^3 + 9}{4p}. \tag{3}$$

Form (2) and (3), it suffices to prove that
$$p + \frac{6}{(p^3 + 9)/(4p)} \ge 5$$
or
$$\frac{(p-3)(p^3-2p^2-6p+15)}{p^3 + 9} \ge 0$$
which is true using $p\ge 3$.

We are done.

Answer (score 0):

Find the minimum of the left hand side of the inequality subject to the condition that $abc=1$ using Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Is it easy? If so, can you give a detailed solution using LM?

Comment: By the way, I didn't downvote you (I found that you were downvoted).  I think it is not easy to do using LM by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Let me prove by Buffalo Way:

$$f(a,b,c)=\frac{1}a+\frac{1}b+\frac{1}c+\frac{6}{a+b+c}-5$$

To prove $f(a,b,c)$ non-negative, let's assume $a<=1<=b,c$ so that we can transform $a=1/bc$, $b=1+p$ and $c=1+q$, where *p* and *q* are non-negative, then:

$$f(a,b,c)=\frac{p^{4} q^{3} + 3 p^{4} q^{2} + 3 p^{4} q + p^{4} + p^{3} q^{4} + 8 p^{3} q^{3} + 13 p^{3} q^{2} + 7 p^{3} q + p^{3} + 3 p^{2} q^{4} + 13 p^{2} q^{3} + 15 p^{2} q^{2} + 6 p^{2} q + p^{2} + 3 p q^{4} + 7 p q^{3} + 6 p q^{2} + p q + q^{4} + q^{3} + q^{2}}{\left(p + 1\right) \left(q + 1\right) \left(p^{2} q + p^{2} + p q^{2} + 4 p q + 3 p + q^{2} + 3 q + 3\right)}$$

which is definitely non-negative, and zero iff $p=q=0$, ie $a=b=c$.

Analogously, assume $a,b<=1<=c$ so that we can transform $c=1/ab$, $a=1/(1+p)$ and $b=1/(1+q)$, then:

$$f(a,b,c)=\frac{p^{4} q^{3} + 3 p^{4} q^{2} + 3 p^{4} q + p^{4} + p^{3} q^{4} + 3 p^{3} q^{3} + 3 p^{3} q^{2} + 2 p^{3} q + p^{3} + 3 p^{2} q^{4} + 3 p^{2} q^{3} + p^{2} q + p^{2} + 3 p q^{4} + 2 p q^{3} + p q^{2} + p q + q^{4} + q^{3} + q^{2}}{\left(p + 1\right) \left(q + 1\right) \left(p^{2} q^{2} + 2 p^{2} q + p^{2} + 2 p q^{2} + 4 p q + 3 p + q^{2} + 3 q + 3\right)}$$

which is also non-negative.

Here is the python code to prove this:

```
from sympy import *

a, b, c = symbols('a, b, c', positive = True)
ineq = 1/a + 1/b + 1/c + 6/(a + b + c) - 5
p, q = symbols('p, q', positive = True)
# a <= 1 <= b, c
print('ineq(a1bc) = ', factor(ineq.subs(a, 1/b/c).subs(b, 1 + p).subs(c, 1 + q)))
# a, b <= 1 <= c 
print('ineq(ab1c) = ', factor(ineq.subs(c, 1/a/b).subs(a, 1/(1 + p)).subs(b, 1/(1 + q))))
```